# Functions which satisfy $f(n)+2f(f(n))=3n+5$

Tags: functional-equations

> I need to find all functions $f:\mathbb N^*\to\mathbb N^*$ that satisfy the relation:
> $$f(n)+2f(f(n))=3n+5.$$

Here $\mathbb N^*$ denotes the set of positive integers.
I have calculated that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=4$.

Observing from this pattern, I could use the arithmetic formula to find one function that satisfying this relation; $a_n=a+(n-1)d$. Substituting $a=1, d=1$:$$a_n=1+n.$$
May I know if there are other functions that satisfy such relation?  Or there is only one function, which is $n+1$ satisfying the relation.

Comment: How did you find that ??

Comment: Are you asking how do I find f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=4? I first find that f(1) must be an even number between 1 and 6 inclusively. And then, I use prove by contradiction to show that f(1) doesn't equal to 4 and 6.

Answer (score 4):

Induction! Suppose $f(n)=n+1$ Then, $$f(n)+2f(f(n))=3n+5$$

is equivalent to $$n+1+2f(n+1)=3n+5$$

so we get $$2f(n+1)=2(n+2)$$

So $f(n+1)=n+2$, which is what we wanted.

Moreover, as you calculated $f(1)=2$, our induction is complete. (note that this is a very important step)

Comment: Thank you so much, so there would be only 1 function satisfying the relation, and that is n+1?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't looked myself into $f(1)=2$. If you cannot prove that, then you cannot use the induction. I am a bit skeptical. However, I repeat, if $f(1)=2$ the only function is $f(k)=k+1$

Comment: What do you mean by "our induction is complete" ?

Comment: If you want to make an induction, there are 2 steps. First of all, state the reccursive result you want to prove, and prove it under the assumption it is true for smaller numbers (in our case, proving $f(n+1)=n+2$ given that $f(n)=n+1$) and second of all, verify the hypothesis for the first value (in our case $n=1$, i.e. $f(1)=2$).

Comment: @Vlad if you assume that $f(n) \in \Bbb N,$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ then you can readily see that $f(1)$ has to be an even number between $1$ and $6$ and that leaves only $3$ possibilities for $f(1).$ Try to show that $f(1) \neq 4,6$ under the assumption.

Comment: If $f(1) = 4$ then $f(4) = 2$ but then $2 + 2 f(2) = 17.$ So $f(2) \notin \Bbb N.$ Similarly if $f(1) = 6$ then $f(6) = 1$ but this implies $1 + 2 f(1) = 23.$ So $f(1) = 11,$ a contradiction to the fact that $f(1) = 6.$ This proves that $f(1) = 2.$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just didn't do the calculations, I never denied it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interesting solution given by user **littletush** in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h446713p2514093.

If we let $g(n)=f(n)-n-1$ and substitute it to the functional equation (this is motivated by observing that $f(n)=n+1$ is at least one of solutions), we get
$$3g(n)=-2g(g(n)+n+1).$$
However then we see $2\mid g(n)$ for all $n$, which in turn means $2 \mid g(g(n)+n+1)$, which in turn means $4 \mid g(n)$, and so on, we can easily prove that generic $2^k \mid g(n)$ for all $k, n$. Only integer that can satisfy this property is $0$ (remember values of $g$ can be also non-positive integers, as opposed to values of $f$), thus we have $g(n)=0$ and so $f(n)=n+1$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=an+b$, then $$f(n)+2f(f(n)=3n+5 \implies an+b+2(a(an+b)+b)=3n+5$$
$$\implies 2a^2+a=3, a+2ab+2b=5$$ $$ \implies a=1, b=1.$$ So $f(n)=n+1.$
The other solution for $a=-3/2$ gives $0=5$ which is invalid.

Comment: You cannot assume $f$ is linear, can you?

Comment: AP means $f(n)$ is a linear function of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a linear function $f(n)=an+b$,

$$an+b+2a^2n+2ab+2b=3n+5$$ and $$\begin{cases}a+2a^2=3,\\(3+2a)b=5\end{cases}$$

The only solution is $a=b=1$.

Of course this says nothing about possible nonlinear solutions. A polynomial cannot do.

---

As explained by @Vlad, we can prove by induction that $f(n)=n+1$.

Indeed,

$$f(n)=n+1\implies n+1+2f(n+1)=3n+5\implies f(n+1)=n+2$$ and $f(1)=2$ is known. So this solution is guaranteed.

Comment: At least, we can determine that a polynomial of degree $1$  is the only solution since $\deg(f(f)) = 2\deg(f) $ if we are seeking for only polynomials. $\ddot\smile$